# Calling activity from two buttons returns different results

Tags: android

Suppose you have two activities A and B. Activity A has two buttons X and Y.Is there any way to receive different results based on what button is calling activity B;

Comment: What are you trying to get? `B displaying "X" or "Y"`? Of course, you can.

Comment: " receive different results based on what button is calling activity B" What? Maybe you mean A?

Comment: Activity B places a marker on google map and gets location lat and lng. Button X represents start city and button Y final city. When button X is pressed, activity B must return start city latlng and when buttn Y is pressed activity B must return finalcity latlng

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this you have to put extras on your intent in the buttons onclicklisteners

```
Intent i = new Intent(context,.class);
i.putExtra("action", "button x") //for button x listener on activity A
i.putExtra("action", "button y") //for button y listener on activity A
```

to know wich one was clicked just do this on activity B

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String result = i.getStringExtra("action");
if(result.equals("button x")) do something
else if(result.equals("button y")) do something
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this :

when button X is pressed

```
intent.putExtra("Data for Activity A", data);
```

when button Y is pressed

```
intent.putExtra("Data for Activity B", data);
```